# FFMPEG MOV to MP4 error {Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument}

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using FFMPEG to convert and watermark videos

```
ffmpeg -i "MVI_9692.MOV"   -i 360.png  -acodec copy -threads 12  -filter_complex "scale=-2:360,overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2"  "MVI_9692.MOV_360.mp4"
```

this command is working OK with diffrent format videos but I got this error message for one of the MOV videos

```
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

and these are the warnings I got before the error message:

```
[swscaler @ 0x47adf20] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly

[mp4 @ 0x4729540] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[mp4 @ 0x4729540] Could not find tag for codec pcm_s16le in stream #1, codec not currently supported in container
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

FFmpeg does not mux PCM audio in MP4 files, so you'll have to convert using a supported codec like AAC, MP3, AC3..etc.

For AAC encoding, use `-c:a aac`

e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i "MVI_9692.MOV" -i 360.png -threads 12 -c:a aac 
       -filter_complex "scale=-2:360,overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2"
       "MVI_9692.MOV_360.mp4"
```

Comment: thanks it works with little change

ffmpeg -i "MVI_9692.MOV" -i 360.png -threads 12 -c:a libvo_aacenc 
       -filter_complex "scale=-2:360,overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2"
       "MVI_9692.MOV_360.mp4"

Comment: You've an old version of FFmpeg. The libvo encoder has been removed, since the native one is now better. Upgrade, and you can use my original command.

Comment: [aac @ 0x1ec04c0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
[aac @ 0x1ec04c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Audio: aac (LC), 7.1, fltp, 323 kb/s): unspecified sample rate
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
video.ts: could not find codec parameters
Input #0, aac, from 'video.ts':
  Duration: 02:11:07.36, bitrate: 323 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 7.1, fltp, 323 kb/s
Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 0 on filter Parsed_scale_0

Comment: @Lebnik seems unrelated to this Q and A. Open a new Q with full command and log.